# When does Firefox throw ssl_error_bad_cert_domain with a wildcard certificate?

Tags: firefox, ssl, wildcard

I've searched through https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/ and Google and still cannot learn exactly why Firefox would display it's "This Connection is Untrusted" screen/UI with "(Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain)" under "Technical Details".

Is it really as simple as "The SSL certificate common name does not match the fully qualified domain name (FQDN) of the webserver/website." ?

If so, then why wouldn't an SSL certificate with the common name "*.subdomain.mydomain.tld" work with the website "https://subdomain.mydomain.tld" and throw this specific error?

Comment: *"... Fully qualified domain name (FQDN)"* - FQDNs end in a dot ".". There's nothing else to them. `www.` and `www.example.com.` are FQDN; `www` and `www.example.com` are not. Browsers regularly mishandle FQDNs. For example, if I enter `wiki.` in my browser bar (note the trailing dot), the browser will take me to a search for wiki rather than connecting to the host named `wiki` on our network.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> If so, then why wouldn't an SSL certificate with the common name "*.subdomain.mydomain.tld" work with the website "https://subdomain.mydomain.tld" and throw this specific error?

A wildcard stands for a single label and not for nothing. That means `*.subdomain.example.com` does not match `subdomain.example.com` but it will match `foo.subdomain.example.com`. To match `subdomain.example.com` too the certificate has to include both `*.subdomain.example.com`  and also `subdomain.example.com` as subject alternative names. Note that `*.example.com` would also match `subdomain.example.com` but not `foo.subdomain.example.com`.

Comment: I misread http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate; "The "naked" domain is also **not** valid[13] (it must be added separately as a SubjectAltName)" (my bold emphasis). So my certificate is in fact incorrect in the way Firefox has thrown, for the reason given here (need SubjectAltName).

https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/567/what-is-a-wildcard-ssl-certificate confused me by stating otherwise, presumably because their sold certs must already have the naked domain name included as a SubjectAltName.